# failure connecting between logstash and logstash-forwarder i/o timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I have a problem with connection between logstash and logstash-forwarder.

The problem is logstash-forwarder send some log files for a while, the connection between logstash and logstash-forwarder will be disconnect.

logstash-forwarder.err

```
2015/08/19  Registrar: processing 1 events
2015/08/19  Registrar: processing 3 events
2015/08/19  Registrar: processing 2 events
2015/08/19  Read error looking for ack: read tcp x.x.x.x:5000: i/o timeout
2015/08/19  Setting trusted CA from file: /etc/pki/tls/certs/lumberjack.crt
2015/08/19  Connecting to [x.x.x.x]:5000 (hostname-example.logstash.com)
2015/08/19  Failure connecting to x.x.x.x: dial tcp x.x.x.x:5000: i/o timeout
```

logstash configuration

```
input{
   lumberjack{
     port=>5000
     ssl_certification => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/lumberjack.crt"
     ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/lumberjack.key"
     type => "secure"
   }
}
filter{
...
...
}
output{
   stdout{
      codec => rubydebug
   }
}
```

logstash version 1.5.1

my vm is on Azure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use Microsoft Azure VM, Now I can solve this problem by create VPN connection via azure virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your timeout setting in logstash-forwarder.

Double-check your logstash configuration that it has been well tuned.